# Rules, Flags, Follower and New Content Notification

Tags: 8, rules, flags

I am trying to setup a couple of rules. So far I have messed with rules some but since I am new, haven't had any success. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Have created a user flag called FOLLOW. (Flag module)

These are the two rules I am trying to set.

1. Every time a user FOLLOWs another user, the user being followed gets an email saying: Hey user [username] is now following you.
2. The second rule will send an email to a user every time someone they follow posts new content of type Article. 
   **Example**: I am an authenticated user following JOE. Every time JOE posts an article I will get an email saying: Hey JOE who you are following just published a new article. Check it at this url [url-link token].

Any help from Rules experts will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the D8 status of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module ? Also, do not **mess** with Rules ...

Comment: Yeah, that is moving very slowly. But why should I not mess with rules? Enlighten me. (Ignorance is a bliss.)

Comment: Dispite the D8- status of Rules, it is great, at least for D7. Which is why it deserves to be handled ***with care***.